# Vimeo API - setVolume has stopped working

Tags: vimeo-api

Until earlier today, the following block of code was running fine to toggle the volume on a Vimeo video.

```
const updateVideoMute = (vimeoPlayer, muteIcon) => {
        vimeoPlayer.getVolume().then(data => {
            data === 0 ? vimeoPlayer.setVolume(1) : vimeoPlayer.setVolume(0);
            data === 0 ? muteIcon.classList.add("active") : muteIcon.classList.remove("active");
        });
    };
```

The checks I have made include:

- Testing other videos from same library (volume has stopped toggling);
- Clearing cache;
- Testing other browsers;
- Double checked the player and methods are behaving as expected.

Has something changed with the API? Any suggestions on how to further investigate the problem?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue, and changing `player.setVolume(1)` to use `player.setMuted(false)` instead has made it work for me.